# Linker command failed Error

Tags: ios, linker-errors, ld, zbar-sdk

i have used Z bar SDK in my app ,when i am trying to archive the file it's showing as 
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/vinodbillakoorti/Desktop/Gift Swap/ProjectSample/ZBarSDK/libzbar.a file '/Users/vinodbillakoorti/Desktop/Gift Swap/ProjectSample/ZBarSDK/libzbar.a' for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

i have removed armv7 from valid architecture but again its showing the above error can any one tell me the solution

Comment: The error is about `armv7s` but you removed `armv7`.  I don't understand.

Comment: i have removed armv7 and tried to archive it but its not worked,so i removed armv7s even though its not worked.

Comment: Set "Build Active Architecture Only" to YES in build settings